# How to initialize pages in jquery mobile? pageinit not firing

Tags: jquery-mobile

What's the right way to initialize objects on a jquery mobile page?  The [events docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) say to use "`pageInit()`" with no examples of that function, but give examples of binding to the "`pageinit`" method (note case difference).  However, I don't see the event firing at all in this simple test page:

```
<html>
 <body>  
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js"></script>

  <div data-role="page" id="myPage">
    test
  </div>

  <script>
    $("#myPage").live('pageinit',function() {
        alert("This never happens");
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?  I should add that if you change `pageinit` to another event like `pagecreate` this code works.

---- UPDATE ----

This [bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2540) is marked as "closed" in the JQM issue tracker.  Apparently opinions differ about whether this is working properly or not.

Comment: I am using RC1, and I have exactly opposite problem, I added pageinit to do event binding for ajax calls. call to pageinit event-method get increased each time the page loaded, e.g. if I visit that page three times, on third visit, same method get called three times. any idea.

Comment: @SutikshanDubey Did you ever figure out why that was happening? I have the same issue...

Comment: @JLaw here are my questions on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741888/jquery-mobile-ajax-navigation-in-single-page-template  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724959/asp-net-mvc3-jquery-mobile-pages-ajax-code-binding-using-pageinit-event and I am doing killing events on hide. But still not satisfied with solution i m using.

Comment: @SutikshanDubey One thing I recently found is that I was inadvertently creating multiple event handlers every time my page was loaded. I had some code within a 'pageshow' handler that would fire on the 'click' event. Every time the 'pageshow' fired a new handler was created for 'click'. Because of this, my handlers went off multiple times. Perhaps you are encountering a similar issue? Do you have multiple handlers performing the same task unknowingly?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It started working when I embedded script within page div:

```
<body>
    <div id="indexPage" data-role="page">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#indexPage").live('pageinit', function() {
                // do something here...
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Used jQuery Mobile 1.0RC1

Comment: Can confirm this solution works with the 1.0 release as well. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: This seems to be just a good habit to get into when using jQuery Mobile - put everything that corresponds to a page inside your <div data-role="page">, then it works whether or not the fragment is loaded with AJAX or not. Although there've been updates addressing this kind of per-page functionality in the later releases, and although it might not seem "clean" as far as XHTML goes, it's just more inline with the way JQM works.

Comment: After a long search, I finally found this in [Jquery Mobile's document](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html): Another approach for page-specific scripting would be to include scripts at the end of the body element when no data-role=page element is defined, or inside the first data-role=page element. So this is by designed.

Comment: That pageinit was what saved me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153236/jquery-mobile-changepage/12546650#12546650

Comment: Thank you SO much. The simple fact that the script needs to be within the page you're binding to is blatantly missing from the jquery mobile docs (at least not in the obvious places, like where examples of this function are!)

Answer (score 21):

`.live()` is deprecated, suggestion is to use `.on()` in jQuery 1.7+ :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pageinit', '#indexPage',  function(){
        // code 
    });
</script>
```

Check the online doc for more information about `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 9):

Turns out this is a [bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2540) in 1.0b3 that is fixed in the current head.  So if you want a fix now, you gotta grab the latest from [git](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile).  Or wait for the next release.

Comment: 1.0 RC1 was just released, and it fixes this issue.

Comment: It doesn't not work with the 'latest' versions from the git HEAD. Did you use those? I just added another comment to the github issue. It still does not work for me. This is my live test (using your code, but with the latest css/js from the git HEAD): http://bit.ly/qlUL7R

Comment: Related bug in RC1 where pageinit does not fire on ajax-loaded pages: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2636

Comment: I just verified it's still a bug in 1.1.

Comment: This bug still exists in 1.3.2, the script only excutes if you place it inside a div

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).live('pageinit',function(event){
    centerHeaderDiv();
    updateOrientation();
    settingsMenu.init();
    menu();
    hideMenuPopupOnBodyClick(); 
})
```

This is working now. Now all page transitions and all JQM AJAX functionality would work along with your defined javascript functions! Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

pageinit will not fire in case it is on secondary pages ( NOT MAIN page ) if it is written in common <script> tag...

I have such a problem - on secondary pages that are not loaded with 'rel="external"', the code in the common <script> tag is never executed...

really this code is always executed...

```
<body>
    <div id="indexPage" data-role="page">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#indexPage").live('pageinit', function() {
                // do something here...
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

althrough if you made "tabbed interface", using of "pageshow" is better

Answer (score 1):

I had to put the script in the HTML page section which to me is a bug. It is loaded normally in a browser (not via AJAX) and all on a single page including javascript. We're not supposed to have to use document ready.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found to deal with this was to use JQM + Steal. It works like a charm as long as you put:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../steal/steal.js?mypage'></script>
```

Inside of the `data-role='page'` div.

Then use AJAX to connect anything that can use the same `mypage.js` and use an external link (by using the `rel="external"` tag) to anything that requires a different steal page.

Answer (score 1):

@Wojciech Bańcer

From the jQuery docs:

```
As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div.page').live('pageinit', function(e) {
    console.log("Event Fired");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#myPage", function(event) {
   alert("This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!");
});
```

Comment: Can you pleas comment your answer more?

Answer (score -2):

The events don't fire on the initial page, only on pages you load via Ajax.  In the above case you can just:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("This happens");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Then why do the docs say "We recommend binding to [pageinit] instead of DOM ready() because this will work regardless of whether the page is loaded directly or if the content is pulled into another page as part of the Ajax navigation system."

Comment: I think we're at cross purposes.  I thought you wanted to know how to change the landing page.  The latest documents say "However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pagecreate event."

Comment: pagecreate also doesn't work for me (in 1.0b3), when the page is loaded via Ajax, only works without Ajax. Is it the same bug as with pageinit?

Comment: Only seems to work when placing the <script> section within the <div data-role="page"> section (unfortunately not really clean html as per xhtml, but oh well...).

Comment: I have a same problem. page init works only when it is placed in the body. This reported as a bug in https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2540 but it is closed. However it looks like a bug to me.