# JQuery Mobile changePage

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am designing a JQuery Mobile application and facing one problem there,
I have two pages, `page1.aspx` and `page2.aspx`, I have to redirect from `page1` to `page2`. Currently I am using `window.location.href` for redirection, but it is show loading also in address bar.

In order to avoid this I want to use `$.mobile.changePage`.

**Problem:**

Now before redirection I am setting one value in `localStorage` variable, based on this value on load event of `page2.aspx` I have to bind the page. It's working fine with `window.location.href`, but while using `$.mobile.changePage` it is redirecting but load event is not firing after coming to `page2.aspx` if I am refreshing the page it is loading.
So my problem is while displaying `page2.aspx` load event has to fire.

Can anyone tell me why `page2.aspx` is not loading while using `$.mobile.changePage`?

If anyone knows the solution, please reply ASAP, its very urgent.

Thanks in advance.

**Page1.aspx:**

```
localStorage.setItem("pageCode", "NULLException");
//$.mobile.changePage("../MessageDialog.aspx", "slide", true, true);
$.mobile.changePage("../MessageDialog.aspx", { transition: "slide", changeHash: true, reverse: false });
```

**Page2.aspx:**

```
 $('div').live("pageshow", function () {
     if (localStorage.getItem("pageCode") != null) {
         if (localStorage.getItem("pageCode") == "NullException") {
                    $('#lblDialogHeader').text("Error");
                    $('#lblDialogMessage').text("Sorry");
                    document.getElementById("btnOK").setAttribute("onclick", 'Test()');
                }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-theme="c" data-role="page" id="test">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1><label id="lblStatus">Status</label></h1> 
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <h3><label id="lblDialogHeader"></label></h3>
            <p><label id="lblDialogMessage"></label></p>
        </div>
         <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                   <a href="#" data-role="button" id="btnOK" data-icon="check">OK</a>       
                    <a href="#" data-role="button"  id="btnCancel"   data-rel="back" data-icon="delete" >Cancel</a>    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to load dynamic listview in jquery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694584/unable-to-load-dynamic-listview-in-jquery-mobile/8694693#8694693) -- I just answered this same question today

Answer (score 3):

It seems that when you call `changepage` specifying a transition, the second page appears to be "injected" into the first one. You can check it easily because `$(document).ready(function(){})` does not work in the second page.

I am using **Cordova** in a **Windows Phone 7** application, I changed my script `location.href` to use `$.mobile.changepage()` and there was this problem: I wanted that the second page to fire any load event, but none worked (`pageshow`, `pagechange`, `pagebeforechange`, body `onload`, `$(document).ready`, etc).

Here are my findings so far that might help you and other people:

the **index.html** is my start page as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callSecondPage() {
            //save my scroll position in index page
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('top', top);
            //go to the second page
            $.mobile.changePage("secondpage.html", { transition: "slide", changeHash: true, reloadPage :true }); 

  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
      <div class="my-page" data-role="page" data-title="My App Title" data-theme="a"> 
          <div class="header" data-role="header"> 
              <img src="img/title.png" />
          </div><!-- /header -->
          <div data-role="content"> 
              <div class="my-logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png"/>
              </div>

              <div class="my-content">
            some stuff here
            <a href="#" onclick="callSecondPage()">Call second page</a>

              </div>
          </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Now the working **secondpage.html**. Understanding that is not possible to use `pagechange` or `$(document).ready`, we notice we can use pageinit to simulate a "page load".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLoad() {
            //LOL! this does not work using $.mobile.changepage as caller
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            //LOL! this will never run using $.mobile.changepage as caller
            // Now safe to use the Cordova API
            var top  = sessionStorage.getItem('top');            
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
      <div class="my-second-page" data-role="page" data-title="App Title" data-theme="b"> 
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(".my-second-page").live('pageinit', function () {
              //LOL! Hey this WORKS! I can see an output in Visual Studio!
              console.log('************************* pageinit');
              console.log('************************* '+ sessionStorage.getItem('top'));
          });
          $(".my-second-page").live('pagechange', function () {
              //LOL! Again, this is not going to work, well, it does not print an output in Visual Studio!
              console.log('************************* pagechange');
              console.log('************************* ' + sessionStorage.getItem('top'));
          });
        </script>
          <div data-role="header"> 
              <h1>App title</h1>
          </div><!-- /header -->
          <div data-role="content"> 
              <div class="my-content">
                   your stuff here for second page                      
              </div>
              <p>
              <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-transition="flip" rel="external" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="left" data-inline="true">Back</a>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div data-role="footer" class="ui-footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>My footer</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a true working sample, if anyone needs I can share a sample project.

Comment: could you check also this one? tnx! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236448/jqueery-mobile-changepage-does-not-work-properly

Answer (score 0):

The events are not the same with changePage, because that method makes an Ajax call to the new  url, that's different from the direct call in window.location.href

Did you tried with this method:

```
$('div').live("pageshow", function()
{
   //your code
});
```

---

EDIT: Looking at the JQuery Mobile page, I saw that there's and event triggered after the page change.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: hi,yes i tried in this way also,but it did't worked,if possible can you post one working sample code for the same

Comment: Hi, I added a link where you can see the events triggered on page change.. Also I my application I'm using the code I posted in my answer and works fine.. Hope you can make it work

Comment: hi,thanks for sharing this link,but i already tried all these events,but none of them is executing at load time,after one refresh everything works,

Comment: Can you add your code when you call the changePage and the js on the second page?

Comment: Page1:                localStorage.setItem("pageCode", "NullException");
                $.mobile.changePage("../MessageDialog.aspx", "slide", true, true);

Comment: That;s not the way you should call changePage, should be like this: $.mobile.changePage("../MessageDialog.aspx", { transition: "slide", changeHash: true, reverse: false });

Comment: $('div').live("pageshow", function () {
  if (localStorage.getItem("pageCode") != null) {
   if (localStorage.getItem("pageCode") == "NullException") {
                    $('#lblDialogHeader').text("Unexpected error");
                    $('#lblDialogMessage').text("Sorry for inconvinence,Please try Again");
                    document.getElementById("btnOK").setAttribute("onclick", 'ShowNewAudit()');
                }
 }
}

Comment: <div data-theme="c" data-role="page" id="test">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1><label id="lblStatus">Status</label></h1> 
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <h3><label id="lblDialogHeader"></label></h3>
            <p><label id="lblDialogMessage"></label></p>
  </div>
        
 </div>

Comment: @Ankit add that code to your question.. in the comments is not possible to read it right..

Comment: I think SERPRO would need to test it before posting. After adding changepage, I have tested many methods (load, pageshow, etc) in jquery mobile and they are not working with the samples provided here

Comment: @JuniorMayhé I tested it and I use it on my mobile sites.. what device/emulator are you using? Sorry to hear that is not working for you