# unable to load dynamic listview in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have create dynamic listview based on database but the problem is to load the listview i have to refresh the page again.

for example ,

Page A.html has a button and Page B.html has a listview

when i click on button which is inside page A.html  page B.html loads but the listview 
is not visible and when i refresh the B.html again then the listview loads.

**Code of page A i.e. index.html** when click on findme page B loads

```
<div data-role="content">   
        <p>
               <a href="findme.html" id="findMeBtn" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Find Me</a>
               <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Fingle Hunts Basic</a>
               <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Communicator</a>  

        </p>


        <p>
         <div id="action">
              <div id="loading-icon"></div>
              <div id="msg"></div>
         </div>
        </p>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

**Code of Page B i.e.findme.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Find Me</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/jquery.mobile.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css"/>

</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page"  id="findme">
    <div data-role="header"  data-theme="b">
        <a href="index.html" data-icon="back">Back</a>
        <h1>VisitFingal</h1>

    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" >  
    <center>
    <div class="vf-nav-view vf-button-panel" >
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-fullscreen="true" >
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button" style="width:30%;" data-theme="b">List</a>
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button" style="width:30%;" data-theme="b">Map</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </center>

    <div id="findMeListView">

    </div>


    </div><!-- End of FindMe Page -->
    <div data-role="page"  id="details">
         <div data-role="header"><h1>Details</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer"  data-theme="b"  data-id="mainfoot" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="findme.html"  class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Find Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Communicatior</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Like</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Favourates</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    </div><!-- /footer -->

    </div>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.js"  type="application/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">

        $(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {



          $.getJSON('getData.php', function(data) {
                  var items = [];
                $page  = $("#findme");
                $content = $page.find("#findMeListView" );
                var listViewData='<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" >';
                for (var i=0; i <data.length;i++)                   
                {
                    listViewData += '<li><a href="details.html?id='+data[i].id+'"><img height="95" width="95" src="'+data[i].url+'" /><h3>'+data[i].name+'</h3></li>';

                }
                     listViewData+='</ul>';

                    $content.html(listViewData);
                    $content.find( ":jqmData(role=listview)" ).listview();



          });


        });

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a multi-page template like this the JS will be ignored when you click from page A to page B. This is because jQuery Mobile AJAX linking pulls just the first `data-role="page` element from the new page and appends it to the current DOM, as you can imagine this ignores any code outside the `data-role="page` element.

Two fixes:

1. Put the JavaScript code for `page B` directly in the `data-role="page` element so it will be parsed when jQuery Mobile does an AJAX load of the page.
2. Put all the code for your site into a single JS include file and include it in the `<head>` of every page; this way all the code for your site will be available whether the user refreshes or deep-links into the site and when they navigate around using jQuery Mobile's AJAX linking. **This is my preferred method.**

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with jQuery Mobile before when loading new pages and content not firing correctly. Mostly with form submissions and database calls. I used a cheap fix by putting the attribute data-ajax="false" on the link loading the page. This way it does a full HTTP REQUEST instead of just an ajax call and loads the DOM and everything.

Here's an example..

```
<a href="findme.html" id="findMeBtn" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-ajax="false">Find Me</a>
```

Comment: The jQuery Mobile framework has a bit of a learning curve but you never need to disable AJAX linking. Most of the time you are probably just declaring JavaScript in an inappropriate place. My favorite method is to package all the JS for the entire site in a single include and include it on each page so it is available to every page no matter how the user got there.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want the direct source code to use in your applications, I have created a free and open source repository on Github.

Please note that, it is currently using JQM 1.1.0
Feel free to download, fork, use, copy the code.

https://github.com/jaydeepw/jquerymobile-dynamic-listview

Cheers!