# JQM event 'pageinit' not fires

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am making a jQueryMobile and PhoneGap app. I need to call ajax in page init. Unfortunately it never fires:

```
$("#kontakty").bind('pageinit', function() {
```

is in the file with:

```
<div data-role="page" id="kontakty">
```

When navigating from page A.html to kontakty.html, my event is not fired. I tried replacing bind with live, but no success. I also tried pageshow, pageinit, pagechange... and all methods form jQM docs.

The weird thing is that, when I change "#kontakty" with document, it works. But I cannot make it permament, because it calls with every other .html file I do open (it is not good).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using .live('pageinit', ...

Comment: "I tried replacing bind with live, but no success" :P

Comment: In which page did you put the javascript A.html or kontacty.html?

Comment: The script is in the "kontakty.html". Is that a problem?

Comment: no thats fine, having a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544023/how-to-initialize-pages-in-jquery-mobile-pageinit-not-firing his JS was not inside the <div data-role... and this was causing issues, maybe try that if you not already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544023/how-to-initialize-pages-in-jquery-mobile-pageinit-not-firing) it could be that your JavaScript is not inside the `<div data-role=..`

I would also change your .bind to a .live as they have in the docs.