# Page Load Event in JQuery Mobile Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

From docs [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html):

```
Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()
```

I have the ff in a JQM page:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function(event){
    //some code here
});
```

The page was loaded via ajax in JQM page, but it was NOT triggered at all. How to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this, it's from the doc

```
$( '#aboutPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );
});
```

Comment: the page is a single jqm page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544023/how-to-initialize-pages-in-jquery-mobile-pageinit-not-firing