# How can I select and animate this collapsible content?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors, children

I'm using jQuery Mobile and I have this html:

```
<ul id="thelist" data-corners= "false" >
<div class = "theListItem" data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed="false">

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="a">
 <h3>$1.48   -  10/31/2012   -   niko Reade #14410  -  Brooklyn Ny</h3>
 <div data-role="controlgroup"  data-type="horizontal">
  <a class= "green" href="categorize.html" data-transition="slide"  data-direction="reverse" data-role="button">Yes</a>
  <a class="red" href="#" data-role="button">No</a>
  <a class= "blue" href="IDontKnow.html" data-transition="slide"data-role="button">I don't know</a>
 </div>
 </div>
</ul>
```

And I'm trying to animate the drop down, but I'm having trouble selecting it.  Here is my JS:

```
$('#transPage, #categorizePage, #IDKPage').live('pageinit', function() {
$('.trans .theListItem h3').click(function() {
     var  $controlGroup = $(this).children('.ui-collapsible-content').css("background-color", "#ff3333");
});
});
```

.ui-collapsible-content works well in the CSS, but doesn't work when I try to use it with JS.  Any idea why my selector is wrong, and how to animate the collapsible content?  Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to select the children, having class 'ui-collapsible-content', but I don't see them in your html..

Comment: No children in your `h3`

Comment: the ui-collapsible-content is a sister to the h3 DOM element, not a child. You should select it with var  $controlGroup = $(this).closest(".ui-collapsible").children('.ui-collapsible-content').css("background-color", "#ff3333");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your HTML markup is incorrect. You're missing a closing `</div>` at the end.
2. `.live` is deprecated. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

   > As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.
   >   Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()
3. There are no child elements inside the `h3` element with the class `ui-collapsible-content`, in fact, there is only text inside the `h3` element.
4. Make sure you have the latest version, because there seem to be some [problems associated with the `pageinit` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544023/how-to-initialize-pages-in-jquery-mobile-pageinit-not-firing) for some of the older ones. Make sure that the event is executed.